# Eclipse - What is the difference between "ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android" and "ArcGIS for Android Apps"?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, arcgis

I am totally new to Eclipse. I am planning to create an ArcGIS Android Application, but currently I am learning it step by step. 
I have a question, is there a difference between "ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android" and "ArcGIS for Android Apps"? & please, tell what it is if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS is a comprehensive system for working with maps and Geographic Information. ( http://resources.arcgis.com/en/home/ )

ArcGis for Android App is an Android app that will help you search, browse and view maps.
You could install this app on your android device. It helps in querying map layers and data. This map has features for measuring area, distance and favourite feature.

ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android is the SDK using which the App ( ArcGIS app for android) is developed. You could use this SDK (ArcGIS runtime SDK) to build application that provide GIS mapping and analysis functionality.